# How to find most accurate tagging for a given sentence using tweet nlp?

Tags: nlp, preprocessor, data-analysis

I found **Twitter nlp** helpful in tagging. It gave all possible tags given a sentence.

"gm sir" gives

Good Morning sir|general manager sir|general motors sir|Good match sir|Game master sir|Good move sir|Grand master sir|Good morning sir.

Is there any way that I can get most suitable replacement for 'gm' depending on input sentence instead of all possible outcomes?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like 'the most suitable replacement' depends on the context. For example, in a page which is mostly about Gaming, 'Game master sir' might be a better match. Have you considered using choosing the best match among these, using some sort of similarity features, based on some contextual data? It seems to be a good starting point

Comment: This looks logically correct. Though, I am not sure, how to get the context out of sentence. Tweet nlp is giving confidence values for words. I am trying to find if confidence scores can somehow help solving my problem. Thanks for taking time to help :)